# Restart application after crash

Tags: ubuntu, cron, nohup

I have some application (net core 2.1 app) which I run like this:

```
nohup dotnet publish/TestApp.dll
```

This application crashes sometimes, and I need to restart it when that happens. What do I need to do?

Comment: Cron a script that checks it's alive using ps and relaunches if crashes.

Comment: Maybe add it as a service using `systemd`, see e.g. https://singlebrook.com/2017/10/23/auto-restart-crashed-service-systemd/ or https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-linux-service-to-start-automatically-after-a-crash-or-reboot-part-1-practical-examples

Comment: @uprego [That is a terrible idea](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#How_can_I_check_to_see_if_my_game_server_is_still_running.3F__I.27ll_put_a_script_in_crontab.2C_and_if_it.27s_not_running.2C_I.27ll_restart_it...).

Answer (score 1):

Use a Process Control System for that matter. [supervisord](http://supervisord.org) is my usual choice as it offers granular choice over several options like number of restart retries, output redirection, process grouping and launch priority, to name a few...

Answer (score 0):

This will restart the application every time it crashes:

```
while true
do
    dotnet publish/TestApp.dll
done
```

[More documentation](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement)